# Shooting in XY direction

Tags: android, game-physics

I want to create a class which shoots on the point where I touch [XY point on my phone screen]. I have searched a lot but I am unable to find any good resource to read from.
I have created a class which can shoot only in X direction. I have also uploaded the image. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Gun {

    private float x, y;
    private int speedX;
    private boolean Visible;
    private Rect rect;

    public Gun (int startX, int startY)
    {
        x = startX;
        y = startY;
        speedX = 220;
        Visible = true;
        rect = new Rect();  
    }

    public void update(float delta)
    {
        x += speedX*delta;
        if (x > 800)
        {
            Visible = false;
        }
        updateRect();
    }

    private void updateRect()
    {
        rect.set((int) x, (int) y, (int) x + 20, (int) y + 10);
    }

    public void onCollideWith(Enemy e)
    {
        Visible = false;
    }
```

*This is the recent code which I have Updated But have a little problem.*

```
    public class Gum {
    private float x,y; // x & y position of the gun
    private float bulletSpeed,speedX,speedY;     
    //speedX and speedY are define to update x & y position of bullets
    private boolean Visible;
    private Rect rect;
    private float handlerX, handlerY; //to get the X and Y value of the touch
    public Gum(int startX, int startY)
        {
          x = startX;
          y = startY;
          bulletSpeed = 220; //
          Visible = true;
          rect = new Rect();
        }
     public void update(float delta)
        {
          x+= speedX*delta;
          y += speedY*delta;
          if(x>800 || y >450)
                {
                    Visible = false;
                 }
         updateBullets();
         updateRect();
        }
     private void updateBullets()
        {   
            handlerX =  InputHandler.scaledX ;
            handlerY = InputHandler.scaledY ;
            //location of the touch - location of the gun
            float deltaX = handlerX - x; 
          /*   THIS DEFINE IN ANOTHER CLASS (InputHandler)
             * scaledX = (int) ((event.getX() / v.getWidth())* *GameMainActivity.GAME_WIDTH);      
             scaledY = (int) ((event.getY() / v.getHeight()) * GameMainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT);

          */

              float deltaY = handlerY - y;
              float length =(float) ( Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2)) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));

              float normalDeltaX = deltaX/ length;
              float normalDeltaY = deltaY/length;

              speedX =  (bulletSpeed * normalDeltaX);
              speedY = bulletSpeed * normalDeltaY;

}
```

**THIS IS THE YOUTUBE VIDEO OF THE PROBLEM  **
 https://youtu.be/C6AdnU_2Qz4

[image: This is the image of the class which I have created, This class can shoot only in single direction]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra) https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors.html

Comment: thanks @selvin. but how can I put all this in java code? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start you need to declare a `speedY` variable in addition to your `speedX` variable. Use it in the update() method to update the `y` position just as you do with `speedX` and the `x` position. Also, you should make the speedX and speedY variables `float` instead of `int`.

Here's what you do to get the bullets going towards the player (do this in the constructor of your class):

```
//First you need to find the tap position.
//In libgdx you can do this using Gdx.input.getX() and Gdx.input.getY()
float tapX = Gdx.input.getX();
float tapY = Gdx.input.getY();

//Calculate the x and y distance from the gun to the tap.
//This gives us a vector between the player and the tap position.
float dx = tapX - x;
float dy = tapY - y;

//Now we need to normalize the vector so that it is of length 1.
//This is so that we can control the speed of the bullet.
//First use the pythagorean theorem to calculate the length of the vector
//(this is the same as the distance between the player and the tap position).
float length = (float)Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

//failsafe to avoid division by zero
if (length == 0)
{
    length = 1;
    dx = 1;
    dy = 0;
}

//Divide the vector components by the length to make it length one.
dx /= length;
dy /= length;

//Now we can calculate the x and y speed of the bullet!
final float bulletSpeed = 220; //change this number to speed up or slow down the bullet
speedX = bulletSpeed * dx;
speedY = bulletSpeed * dy;
```

If you have any questions about this, feel free to ask.

Comment: What if he exactly tap on the gun? 
Lenght will be zero and he will get divided by zero runtime error.

Comment: True, forgot about that. Added a check for that

Comment: @AlfredAndersson   First of all thanks for helping me Sir.With your help I am able to create a class where bullets can move in XY direction but with a little problem. Now bullets is not leaving the screen they are just going where i touch. I am updating the code with the recent class which i have created and giving the link of video which will show you what is happening in screen.Hope you will help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is because you are setting the speed every frame in the updateBullets() method. You are only supposed to set it once, in the constructor so that it remains constant.

Comment: @AlfredAndersson Thanks Sir for helping.But there is a problem in Class. As you said (1) If I initialize speedX and speedY int constructor then the bullet not even move anywhere. (2) if I am directly Multiplying in the update method. { x= (bulletSpeed * normalDeltaX)*delta}. Then also bullets are going where I am touching.Please help. And once again Thank you for Helping me.

Comment: How does your code look? If you just move the entire contents of the updateBullets() method to the end of the constructor it should work.